# The good old beginnerkiller: Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently studying C and reached the point (haha...) where I am learning about pointers. I think I know a bit about them already and I think I get the concept of them.

If I have a pointer named "c" and an integer named "a" with the value of 5 and I do the following:

```
*c = a;
```

I set the value of the pointer c (because I am using the asterik symbol) to the value of a, which is 5. So *c is 5 after that and c is equal to the memory address of a - Correct?

What about the following then:

```
c = &a;
```

I just pass the memory address in which the value of a is stored to the pointer. 
Are both operations equal? From my point of view they do the same - Is that correct?

Comment: "I set the value of the pointer c" => NO. You set the value pointed by c. The value of the pointer c is the address it points at.

Comment: You might want to read on how the address-of operator `&` works,  as well as how the dereference operator `*` works ans also how the latter differs from the usage of a `*` in type/variable definitions.

Comment: Especially "latter differs from the usage of a * in type/variable definitions" was confusing me. Got it cleared up now! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
*c = a;
```

You will end up with this:

```
+---+     +---+    +---+
| A |     | C |    | ? |
+---+     +---+    +---+
| 5 |     | @ |    | 5 |
+---+     +-+-+    +-+-+
            |        ^
            |        |
            +--------+
```

Howerver with:

```
c = &a;
```

you'll end up with:

```
+---+     +---+
| A |     | C |
+---+     +---+
| 5 |     | @ |
+---+     +-+-+
  ^         |
  |         |
  +---------+
```

So in in both cases, you'll have `*c == 5`, but what differs is **what c points to**.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I find that pointers are only tricky when you need to describe them in plain English/NaturalLanguageX instead of just using them. By using this visualization that pitfall is cleverly avoided. Well done.

Comment: @Will : Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

Almost. Keep in mind that the first one you are saying: "take the portion of memory where 'c' points to and makes it equal 5". Therefore, you need to assign which portion of memory is that, before setting it to 5. So you actually have two different variables ('a' and the one 'c' points to).

In the second case you are just assigning 'c' to point to 'a'. So yea, you will again point to a value 5 but now you have only one variable 'a' and a pointer pointing to that same space of memory

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

> If I have a pointer named "c" and an integer named "a" with the value
>   of 5 and I do the following:
>
> `*c = a;` I set the value of the pointer c (because I am using the asterik symbol) to the value of a, which is 5. So *c is 5 after that
>   and c is equal to the memory address of a - Correct?

No, the contents of **the variable that `c` is pointing to** will get the value of the variable `a`. The pointer itself is not changed.

> What about the following then:
>
> `c = &a;` I just pass the memory address in which the value of a is
>   stored to the pointer.

This changes **the pointer `c` itself** to point to the variable `a`.

> Are both operations equal? From my point of view they do the same - Is that correct?

No, the first changes the value of whatever `c` points to, the second one changes what the pointer points to.

An important difference is that the first (`*c = a`) requires that `c` is valid -- i.e. actually points to an object). The second one makes `c` a valid pointer, overwriting its previous value.

Comment: So basically the second step includes the first one as well right? Because if I assign the address of a using &a to the pointer, I can access what is stored inside the address using the asterik operator - Correct?

Comment: Not really, as the first one changes another object that the pointer points to, whereas the second one "reseats" the pointer.  The fact that `*c' will be 5 after both is not the important thing, as they are different fives.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `*c=a` it will assign 5 to memory address where `c` is pointing, and if you change value of `a` it will not affected to value of `c`.

While if you use `c=&a` than `c` started to pointing to memory address of `a` and of you changed the value of `a` it will change the value where `c` is pointing(`*c`).